# checkbox in a gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I'm having trouble with my gridview - basically i want to have a checkbox in each row and to be able to check off certain rows and have this update to a database after hitting 'Submit'   I have the checkbox in a templatefield:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve?">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ckbxApprove" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and in the code end:

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow oRow in GridView1.Rows)
 {
 CheckBox bchecked = (CheckBox)oRow.FindControl("ckbxApprove");
  if (bchecked.Checked)
  {
//Do something
  }
}
}
```

However, if i check off the boxes in my gridview and hit the Submit button, none of the check boxes are marked as 'Checked'
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine you might be binding grid again on postback in page_load event. It is one of the common reason for losing state of controls on post back is not binding the control in IsPostBack block.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     // bind grid here
}
```